# Error on loading Sales in Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I become en Shop-Error on Magento 1.9 when I will call the Sales in Backend. 
Where can I found the problem?

Here are the Logfile

```
a:5:{i:0;s:50:"Die angeforderte Zahlungsart ist nicht verfügbar.";i:1;s:7570:"#0 /xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('Die angefordert...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(259): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(481): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->canCapture()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(176): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract->canEditQty()
/xxxxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml(59): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Abstract->getItemHtml(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item))
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/349373_...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(103): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Sales/Items/Abstract.php(112): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Sales_Items_Abstract->_render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Sales_Items_Abstract->render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
/xxxxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bl/customgrid/widget/grid/16.phtml(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/349373_...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
/xxxxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/349373_...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
/xxxxx/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/kunden/349373_...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
/xxxxx/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
/xxxxx/index.php(132): Mage::run('', 'store')
 {main}";s:3:"url";s:29:"/index.php/admin/sales_order/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you disable or delete an extension that provides a payment method, and afterwards try to access an order that was paid with this method.

Have you disabled a payment extension recently?

If you don't know which payment method has been used for this order, search the `sales_flat_order_payment` table in your database for a row with the order ID from the URL.

You should re-install (or re-enable) this extension to get rid of this error. Another possibility (though not recommended) is to change the payment method in the database to something still enabled, for example "checkmo" or "bankpayment".

Comment: I found the bad payment method and solve it. Thankx

Comment: Nice :) please accept the answer to mark the question as solved